# Credit card validation with angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

How to validate the credit card number based on credit card type?

I am designing the form where I have two fields firts on is shows **Credit Card's** type and the second one is for **Credit Card's Number**. How to validate the credit card number based on credit card type? I know about custom `validator` to apply on `creditcardnumber` field and validating from the `regex`, but when user changes the type of credit card then  `validator` on `creditcardnumber` will not call.

I don't want to set `validator` on `FormGroup` level, because my form contains 50+ properties and that is the performance bottleneck(I believe).
Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Also basic validation can be performed with Luhn algorithm.

It is not intended to be a cryptographically secure hash function; it was designed to protect against accidental errors, not malicious attacks. Most credit cards and many government identification numbers use the algorithm as a simple method of distinguishing valid numbers from mistyped or otherwise incorrect numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

```
function isValid(digits) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        let cardNum = parseInt(digits[i]);

        if ((digits.length - i) % 2 === 0) {
            cardNum = cardNum * 2;

            if (cardNum > 9) {
                cardNum = cardNum - 9;
            }
        }

        sum += cardNum;
    }

    return sum % 10 === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your stuff by using some npm packages, 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-credit-cards

Answer (score 0):

form the https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance:

> By default, all validators are run after every form value change...We can delay updating the form validity by changing the updateOn property from change (default) to submit or blur

After this, you can change the validation using setValidators, applying only in changes of the cardType

```
this.form.get('cardType').valueChanges.subscribe(cardType=> {
      switch (cardType)
      {
          case 1:
             this.form.get('cardNumber').setValidators(.....);
             break;
          ...
      }

      this.form.get('cardNumber').updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

Or make a customValidator that get two values (the cardType and the cardNumber)

```
customValidator2(params: any) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      let form=control.parent;
      if (form)
      {
        let cardType=form.get('cardType').value;
        let cardNumber=form.get('cardNumber').value;
        switch (cardType)
        {
              case 1:
                 ....
                 break;
         }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Or make a customValidator at level of Form: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation