# IP V4 and V6 Validation Conditionally in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am struggling to validate the IPV4 and IPV6 conditionally based on checkbox selection and the other problem is my IPV6 regex is incorrect.

I have searched some of answered on SO which are related to IPV6 Regex, but doesn't helpful in my case.
My Valid IP V6 are below:

1::

0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001

Below is my TS Code:

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators } from "@angular/forms"

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  
  networkForm:FormGroup
  constructor(private newFormBuilder:FormBuilder){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.networkForm = this.newFormBuilder.group({
      //ipv4 pattern.
      ip:['',[Validators.pattern(/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/),Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  ipSelect(ipType:string){
    ///what to do here
      if(ipType == "v4"){

      }else{

      }
      
  }
}
```

For Conditional Validation, I know about global validator to set on FormGroup level or value change subscription to apply the validator or removing the validator. Because I have lots of other validation things in my form, which I haven't mentioned here. This is the reason I am looking for other good approach. If someone suggest.

Below is my HTML code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="networkForm">
<input type="checkbox" value="v4" (click)="ipSelect($element.target.value,'v4')"/> IP V4<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="v6" (click)="ipSelect($element.target.value,'v6')"/> IP V6<br/>

<input type="textbox" formControlName="ip"/>
{{networkFrom.controls.ip.errors | json}}
</form>
```

Please help.

Comment: You can subscribe to valueChanges and then based on your value you can put validations.

Comment: For the IPV6 validation, [some resources are available online](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipv6%20regex&rlz=1C1GCEU_frFR819FR820&oq=ipv6%20regex&aqs=chrome..69i57.1480j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), such as [this one](https://www.regextester.com/25). About the validator, you **have to** put it at form level, because it involves two controls. [I have already answered on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896656/angular-4-validator-to-check-2-controls-at-the-same-time/49897087#49897087), so I'll close this one as duplicate.

Comment: Complementary @Raj response, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885776/credit-card-validation-in-angular-reactive-form/54094180#54094180

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks for the comment, but please unmark this question as duplicate, I have clearly mentioned that I don't want to use global validator or value subscription and your provide regex link isn't validate this ip : 1::8

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for the comment. This is not helpful for me.

Comment: @AmiVyas if you cared to read the link I have provided, you would have seen my own answer explaining how to keep the validation at control level. So this is indeed a duplicate, because you already have an answer over there.

Comment: @trichetriche So in angular these are global and value subscription is the two practices. none of the other things are available, this is what you are saying?

Comment: There are plenty of solutions, but only a few are good practices. What you're asking here is basically recoding Angular's form validation process : it's useless. Stick to what is already existing, and gain a lot of time !

Comment: @trichetriche Think little bit bigger aspect of the application, as i mentioned in the question. I have lots of other validation. if there are plenty of solutions then why do you judge this question is duplicate. lets wait for others to give the answer. if you help me out with other good approach, I don't mind.

Comment: Re-read carefully : **there is no other good approach**. There is one single good approach, and it has been implemented by the framework itself. If you want to go against that, then go ahead. But don't ask how to validate 2 form controls : ask how to rewrite the framework because you don't like the way you have to implement a validator. As far as I'm concerned, your actual question has already been answered on the post I have given you.

Comment: I you have "lots of other validation", the principle doesn't change. You just create a reusable validators, which is a simple function. **This**, is the good approach : reusable validator, declared at form group level. This is good design, easy coding, and it doesn't go against the framework.